# What class/object to invoke in order to run Scala Spark job built from source?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've setup Spark core project from https://github.com/apache/spark.git. I've invoked one of the test classes : `CacheManagerSuite` and it passes.

How to run some Spark transformations/actions on the source? What class/object do I need to invoke within Spark project source in order to run below : ?

```
scala> val x = sc.parallelize(List(List("a"), List("b"), List("c", "d")))
x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> x.collect()
res0: Array[List[String]] = Array(List(a), List(b), List(c, d))

scala> x.flatMap(y => y)
res3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = FlatMappedRDD[3] at flatMap at <console>:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark core project contains unit tests which make it clearer how parallelize & reduce methods are called & implemented.

In `org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleanerSuite` there is call to `TestClassWithoutDefaultConstructor`

`org.apache.spark.util.TestClassWithoutDefaultConstructor` calls to parallelize & reduce methods of Spark :

```
class TestClassWithoutDefaultConstructor(x: Int) extends Serializable {
  def getX = x

  def run(): Int = {
    var nonSer = new NonSerializable
    withSpark(new SparkContext("local", "test")) { sc =>
      val nums = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
      nums.map(_ + getX).reduce(_ + _)
    }
  }
}
```

Similarity `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctionsSuite` contains method calls to `groupByKey`

Above tests compile and run on local machine

Answer (score 0):

To experiment with Spark, like in your quoted example, start `bin/spark-shell`.